# Is there a way to zip part of the values in list using zipWithNext kotlin?

Tags: lambda, kotlin

In the official documentation of the Kotlin language there is a function zipWithNextthat is presented as follows.

```
val letters = listOf("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
val pairs = letters.zipWithNext {a, b -> a + b} // [ab, bc, cd, de, ef]
```

Is there a way to summarize only part of the elements of this list, and leave the rest unchanged?
For comparison, you can use another `listOf("bc", "de")`.
In this case the final output should looks like `[a, bc, de, f]`

Comment: maybe some condition in lambda will help? For example `val pairs = letters.zipWithNext {a, b -> if (a.length > 1 || b.length > 1) {
            return@zipWithNext a
        }
        return@zipWithNext a + b}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the initial list's size is an even number, otherwise you cannot get your expected result. 
For

```
val letters = listOf("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
```

with `zipWithNext()`:

```
val pairs = (listOf("") + letters + listOf(""))
        .zipWithNext()
        .filterIndexed { index, _ -> index % 2 == 0 }
        .map { it.first + it.second }
```

with `chunked(2)`:

```
val pairs = listOf(letters.first()) + 
            letters.subList(1, letters.size - 1).chunked(2).map { it[0] + it[1] } + 
            listOf(letters.last())
```

both give this result:

```
[a, bc, de, f]
```

**Edit**
As for the comparison list:

```
fun getNewList(list: List<String>, comparison: List<String>) : List<String> {
    val newList = mutableListOf<String>()
    var flag = false
    list.forEachIndexed { i, s ->
        if (i < list.size - 1) {
            if (!flag) {
                val item = s + list[i + 1]
                if (comparison.contains(item)) {
                    newList.add(item)
                    flag = true
                } else {
                    newList.add(s)
                }
            } else {
                flag = false
            }
        } else {
            newList.add(s)
        }
    }
    return newList
}
```

this code:

```
val letters = listOf("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
val comparison = listOf("bc", "de")
val newList = getNewList(letters, comparison)
println(newList)
```

will print:

```
[a, bc, de, f]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please tell me how you can do the same thing, but with a comparison of the result of the function zipWithNext with the previously announced `listOf("bc", "de")`

Comment: In other words, write to the final list only those values that are in this list. The rest remain unchanged.

Comment: There is the initial list: `listOf("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")` and this: `listOf("bc", "de")`. If you apply `zipWithNext()` to the initial list you get: `[(a, b), (b, c), (c, d), (d, e), (e, f)]`. What comparison do you want in this result?

Comment: I would like the function to work not only on this example. If we simplify the comparison list to `listOf("bc")`, how can i get this result? `[a, bc, d, e, f]`

Comment: See my edited answer. If I understood your requirements this is an algorithmic solution that does not involve `zipWithNext()`.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for your help!